# Finding the minimum distance between two arbitrary integers in the set of positive integers under multiplication, generated by the first $k$ primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $N = \{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \mid n = p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_k^{\alpha_k}\}$, where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number and $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Suppose that we are given some arbitrary $n \in N$. Does there exist a method for minimising $\delta = |n - n'| > 0$, where $n'$ also lies in $N$? (In particular, the condition that $\delta > 0$ implies $n \neq n'$).

I've looked around and can't find any problems similar to this one. Any insight into how this problem may be tackled is appreciated. I'm mainly interested in behaviour for large $n$, for some fixed $k$.

Edited for inclusion of example:

Suppose I consider the set $P= \{2,3,5,7\}$. If I considered $n = 49$, then $\delta = 1$ since $50 = 2\cdot 5^2$ (or alternatively, because $48 = 2^4\cdot 3$). However, for $n = 98$, we have $\delta = 2$ since $99 = 3^2\cdot 11$ and $11 \notin P$, and $97$ is itself prime and not contained in $P$. For $n = 196$, it turns out that $\delta = 4$, and for $n = 392$, we have $\delta = 8$. I suspect that for large values of $n$, the value of $\delta$ should also be large.

Comment: Taking logs, it's the same as minimizing $|\log n-(\alpha_1\log p_1+\alpha_2\log p_2+\cdots+\alpha_k\log p_k)|$.

Comment: So the constraints would be that each $\alpha_i$ must be a natural number, and that $\delta$ must be a positive integer (in particular, non-zero)?

Comment: @user1239334 There is no constraint on $\delta$. You minimize the $\log$-expression Gerry gave you. Once you have done this, you compute $\delta=|n-p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}|$ like you did before. The $\log$-expression is just there to determine the $\alpha_i$.

Comment: Since $n$ itself is in $N$, it has a prime factorisation $p_1^{\beta_1}\dots  p_k^{\beta_k}$. What then stops one from choosing $\alpha_1 = \beta_1, \dots, \alpha_k = \beta_k$, making $\delta = |n - n|  = 0$ for all $n \in N$?

Comment: I didn't notice that $n$ was in $N$. So you are trying to find the closest integer in $N$ to an integer in $N$? Then of course the answer is to take $n'=n$, giving $\delta=0$. But surely that's not what you want. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Anyway, for the case $k=2$, you might look at http://oeis.org/A003586 and for the general case, you might find https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256067456 interesting, also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Størmer%27s_theorem

Comment: Also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106738/for-any-prime-p-is-there-c-such-that-if-x-ge-c-then-all-but-one-integer

Comment: There is no upper bound for  $\delta (n)$  for if $\delta(n)\leq K$ for all $n$ then for each $m\in \Bbb N$, the interval $[Km, K(m+1)-1]$ contains a member of $N$, implying $\sum_{x\in N}(1/x)\geq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(K(m+1))^{-1}=\infty.$... But $\sum_{x\in N}(1/x)= \prod_{j=1}^k(1-p_j^{-1})^{-1}.$

Comment: Have you had a look at those references, 1239334?

Comment: I've looked at the projecteuclid one -- the results were helpful for my purposes. I didn't quite understand the procedure since I wasn't familiar with Pell equations prior to asking my question. If I did, I would use it to find all the solutions for $t = 26$, or $p_t = 103$. As for the mathoverflow link, I'm still trying to get my head around what the implication of the question is in that link, in relation to my own. Nonetheless, I am appreciative of all the references you left.